# Combing text and character in ARKit cause text to start flashing?

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

I am using sample robot character from [WWDC2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/607/) RealityKit demo. In my sample project, I am trying to provide a 3D text for character name but combining both text and model entities cause the text to start flickering. Is there a reason why this flicker is happening?
[Demo Video](https://vimeo.com/571445342)

Edit: Add source code

Testing further, the 3D text anchor works by itself when added to a ARView. When combined to a character anchor and text anchor. The character text starts blinking. Here is the source code below.

```
    if let previewCharacter = previewCharacter, previewCharacter.parent == nil {
            characterAnchor.addChild(previewCharacter)
            characterAnchor.addChild(textAnchor)
            textAnchor.setPosition(SIMD3<Float>(0, 1.25, 0.05), relativeTo: characterAnchor)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could provide **the full code**, or at least the reference code you are using, so we can have a better understanding of this.
You can provide an attached **link to a dropbox** share for example to make this easier.

From the top of my head, this could be an issue in which the text and the model are on the same Z position.

Again, without the full code, it will be very hard to determine.